# Is there a simpler way to know links that were clicked on several sub-domains, via tag manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-firebase

There are several sub-domains, many get created as users sign-up. I want to track every link clicked on every subdomain and get in the report. Can I track all clicks and drill down on what was clicked in any way? OR, I need to manually add link tracking of each links on each sub-domain?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you assume that GTM is somehow bothered with the hostname it runs on. This is not the case, GTM does not care about the domain or subdomain.

You just need to include your GTM code on all pages on your subdomain. GTM has a built-in click trigger (actually two, one specifically for links and one for all clickable elements). If you enable the built-in variables you can also access classes, ids, href and the text of clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set up a GA event through GTM that uses variables for the Event Category / Action / Label.

You can try:

Category = `{{Page Hostname}}` (this will give you `subdomain.mydomain.com`. If you just want the subdomain, you'll probably have to use a custom variable to strip it out of the URL).

Action = `{{Click Text}} | {{Click URL}}`

Label = use this for a custom field if you want to write a custom variable to pull out where the link was (e.g. the nav, footer, etc.)